# Creating carousel using LinkedIn APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have been trying to use the LinkedIn APIs to post a carousel.
I looked into the documentation but the only mention of Carousel is in Carousel Ads.

Upon some research, I could see that the PDF is being converted to images and then used as the carousel.

Some applications like [Taplio](https://taplio.com/), and [Supergrow](https://app.supergrow.ai/) have the feature to post Carousels.

I tried using "/v2/ugcPosts/" API to post images by setting "shareMediaCategory": "CAROUSEL" (based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/integrations/shares/ugc-post-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true&tabs=http)).

But I got the following error:

```
{
  "message": "com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: Carousel post must be a sponsored post: {lifecycleState=PUBLISHED, specificContent={com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent={shareCommentary={text=Testing}, shareMediaCategory=CAROUSEL, media=[{thumbnails=[], status=READY, media=urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ASSET_URN}, {thumbnails=[], status=READY, media=urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ASSET_URN}]}}, visibility={com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility=PUBLIC}, author=urn:li:member:URN, clientApplication=urn:li:developerApplication:ID, ugcOrigin=API, id=urn:li:share:ID, distribution={feedDistribution=MAIN_FEED}}.",
  "status": 403
}
```

Here is the payload:

```
{
  "author": "urn:li:person:USER_URN",
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
      "shareCommentary": {
        "text": "Testing"
      },
      "shareMediaCategory": "CAROUSEL",
      "media": [
        {
        "status": "READY",
        "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ASSET_URN"
      },
      {
        "status": "READY",
        "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:ASSET_URN"
      }
        ]
    }
  },
  "visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
  }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards.

I was trying to post a carousel on LinkedIn using "Share on LinkedIn" APIs

**Update:**
I am specifically trying to use PDFs to create carousels as LinkedIn UI does using APIs. But there is no documentation to do so.

Comment: The message you get from the API is clear: "Carousel post must be a sponsored post". Carousel posts cannot be made without payment and must have some form of sponsorship associated with them.

Comment: Check this page: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a421188/?src=or-search&veh=www.google.com

Comment: Hey @MarcoMerola, thank you for replying. I understand the message I got from the API. But I'm trying to check if there is a way to create Carousel Posts (not ads) using these APIs or is there any alternative to achieve this.

Comment: No. LinkedIn said goodbye to Carousel Posts https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/linkedins-evolution-goodbye-carousels-in-image-linking-profile-aosyc

Comment: Hey @MarcoMerola, in the post you shared, it says "Users will have to adapt and possibly revert to the previous method of uploading PDFs to create makeshift carousels if they are removed.", which is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: That's a different thing. It's not a Carousel Post:
"uploading PDFs with each page representing a separate slide is still available as a workaround for users"

Comment: @MarcoMerola can we upload a PDF using the APIs?

Comment: Never done it but seems achievable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/documents-api?view=li-lms-2024-02&tabs=http#upload-the-document

Comment: @MarcoMerola I had tried these but these are deprecated and returns this: {
  "status": 404,
  "code": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
  "message": "No virtual resource found"
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.